# How to establish connection between Web & Database (windows base) docker container , running through docker-compose file?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, windows-container

Docker engine is running on AWS windows server 2016

Here is docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
     controllerdb:
            hostname: controllerdb
            image: <windows base mysql image>
            restart: always
     web:
            hostname: web
            depends_on: 
                - controllerdb
            image: <windows base tomcat image>
            restart: always
            ports:
                - 8080:8080
            links:
                - controllerdb
networks:
     default:
         external:
            name: nat
```

For connecting with database URL in tomcat

> URL = jdbc:mysql://controllerdb:3306/database_name"

But on running compose file its giving error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not 
 received any packets from the server.
 **Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: controllerdb**
```

Even after providing correct hostname , its giving UnknownHostException.

This connection work with linux container but I want to establish it in windows container.

Please , let me know how to fix it, So that inter container communication in windows containers can be done.

Comment: `links:` is an obsolete setting from first-generation Docker networking; does deleting that setting make any difference here?

Comment: not it does not make any difference, error remains the same.

Comment: Are there any `networks:` settings in the file at all?  ("No" is a good answer.)  To confirm, the error you quote is a startup-time error from the `web` container coming from the `docker-compose up` output?  Does the database container start up successfully?

Comment: Its using default network of driver nat , and yes database is starting up successfully before the web container start.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3'
services:
     controllerdb:
            hostname: controllerdb
            image: <windows base mysql image>
            restart: always
            networks:
                - app-network
     web:
            hostname: web
            depends_on: 
                - controllerdb
            image: <windows base tomcat image>
            restart: always
            ports:
                - 8080:8080
            networks:
                - app-network
networks:
    app-network
```

the DNS for your database would be `controllerdb:your-port`,

Comment: This is identical to the `docker-compose.yml` file in the question, except that the containers are connected to a network named `app-network` instead of a network named `default`.

Comment: Well, this one works, as links are deprecated

Comment: no, even after this error remains the same.